# Assigning identifier to the duplicate values in SQL data

Tags: java, mysql

I have a table which have two attributes id and string. Now in my data most of the strings are have duplicate values and most of the strings also share the same values, but their order are not same like shown in the table below:

```
id  | String
144 | gall stones
144 | gallstones
241 | coats tire equipment
241 | tire equipment coats
144 | google
241 | google
```

Now I want to add third column which shows that to which set string belongs. like gall stones and "gall stones" and "gallstone" belongs to same set as both contains same strings or "coats tire equipment" and "tire equipment coats" belongs to same set. In short, I want to create the following table using mysql or java or by any easy means. As my data have 3.5 million records.

```
id  | String               | Set
144 | gall stones          | s1
144 | gallstones           | s1
241 | coats tire equipment | s2
241 | tire equipment coats | s2
144 | google               | s3
241 | google               | s3
```

Comment: The supposed ordering you intend to use is not clear.  Can you provide a query which generates the records in the order you want in your output (the `Set` column missing)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly suggest breaking this out in to two separate tables, adding Primary keys and Foreign keys to them.  The first table would be like this:

String_table

```
seq_num (pk) | id  | String               | set_seq_num (fk)
1            | 144 | gall stones          | 1
2            | 144 | gallstones           | 1
3            | 241 | coats tire equipment | 2
4            | 241 | tire equipment coats | 2
5            | 144 | google               | 3
6            | 241 | google               | 3
```

set_table

```
seq_num (pk) | set_id
1            | s1
2            | s2
3            | s3
```

I don't know what other info you plan on storing or referencing for the sets but keeping them in a different table and then joining in a sql to get the data seems like the best option to me

```
Select string_t.id, string_t.string, set_t.set_id 
from string_table as string_t
inner join set_table as set_t 
on string_table.set_seq_num = set_table.seq_num
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. my one problem is solved but my other problem is that "how we will find out that our two strings for example 1 =  "coats tire equipment" and 2= "tire equipment coats" belongs to same data set. especially if i have a data set of 1.6 million records